# Multiple PersistenceUnits and DataSources using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know there are quite a few questions on my topics already, but I haven't really been completely satisfied with any of the answers. It's also difficult to find decent information on the web, so I'm starting a new question.

Basically, I'm struggling with how to best use JPA in a Spring application for a scenario that must comply to the following requirements:

- Using Spring Transaction management
- Using multiple Persistence Units (with Spring Data Repository support)
- Using multiple DataSources (I want to be able to switch the DataSource for a PersistenceUnit dynamically at runtime)
- Combining parts of the application (that include JPA entities) in separate modules to use them in different projects

Consider the following UseCase

- Application A allows the User to read and write DB data from different DataSources, D1, D2, Dn. I only need a single PersistenceUnit P1 to define the needed entities
- Module M contains two entities AuthUser and AuthRole that are used to store user and permission information. I'd like to use it modularly in different projects. Basically, I need to be able to define the PersistenceUnit P2 that only contains the two entities and a DataSource Da as the users are stored in ONE database, independent from the other DataSources D1, D2, ... the application accesses.
- Application A includes Module M and defines which DataSource it should use

The issues i ran into:

- I would like to use @PersistenceContext and @Transactional in Module M, without having to specify explicit persistenceUnits or transactionManagers everywhere. Ideally, Spring would use the PersistenceContext / EntityManager of a running Transaction. This way, I would specify the desired PersistenceUnit in a transactional method of Application A and Module M would inherit the transaction and PersistenceContext. I couldn't find a solution of how to do this. I was thinking  of providing a custom PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, but I couldn't find any resources on the web on this subject.
- To use multiple DataSources with the same PersistenceUnit, I looked into AbstractRoutingDatatSource. This should work, even though I'm suspisous on how it will cooperate with the Transactional annotation. Any experience on using it and on how to prevent changing DataSources in the middle of a transaction?

I hope I could make my point clear. I didn't want to include too much code as in a first instance, I'm interested more in the conceptual answer than the technical one. To boil it down to one (large) sentence:

**What's the best practice in Spring / JPA to build modular, transactional applications using multiple PersistenceUnits and DataSources without having to specify hard coded persistence information (like persistenceUnit names) in the source code (especially of the modules)?**

Comment: Oh yes, a little follow-up: I have some workarounds in mind that would require me to define the persistence name in @PersistenceContext, e.g. in the modules. But in this case, I would want to specify a default PersistenceUnit. I couldn't find a way how to specifiy this...

Comment: Another follow-up: How can I specify the PersistenceUnit of an existing bean that uses a blank @PersistenceContext. Is there a way to configure / override this in beans.xml?